# Using Hashalgorithm with ReadOnlySpan<byte>

Tags: c#, html, hash, .net-core, unsafe

I'm rewriting my application for speed. It basically uses a Producer/Consumer pattern to process file data to calculate for example multiple hashes in parallel.

One of the changes was to switch from byte[] Blocks to ReadOnlySpan. This resulted in some nice speedups and code simplifications.

There is only one mayor catch:
I've had to remove all HashAlgorithms supported by the Framework since as of yet they don't support processing partial Span data. Remove them or suffer the penalty for copying the data into byte Arrays.
The only method which supports Span is TryComputeHash which wants the complete Data.
Since the files to be processed can be very large, this is of no use to me.

So here is my actual question:
**Is there any (possibly unsafe) "hack" I could use to pass Span data to HashAlgorithm objects?**

```cs
protected override void DoWork(CancellationToken ct) {
    HashAlgorithm.Initialize();

    ReadOnlySpan<byte> block;
    int bytesProcessed;
    do {
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        block = Reader.GetBlock(ReadLength);
        //Make this work
        bytesProcessed = HashAlgorithm.TransformBlock((byte[])block, 0, block.Length, null, 0); 
    } while(Reader.Advance(bytesProcessed) && bytesProcessed != 0);

    var lastBytes = block.Length - bytesProcessed;
    //Make this work
    HashValue = HashAlgorithm.TransformFinalBlock((byte[])block.Slice(bytesProcessed, lastBytes), 0, lastBytes).ToArray(); 
    Reader.Advance(lastBytes);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[incrementalhash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.incrementalhash?view=netstandard-2.1) is suggested for your case. It can process with continuous data in `Span<byte>` type.

Comment: I wondered why `IncrementalHash` even needs to exist as it offers nothing new, instead it just duplicates the functionality of `HashAlgorithm`, albiet with a simpler and harder-to-misuse API surface (and the docs talk about it being intended for HMAC applications rather than general-purpose hashing) - [then I saw this thread which explains it's something they tried-out for .NET Core 1.x](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30331) - though I've yet to see it go anywhere...